# What is the main difference between mutationobserver and addeventlistener?

Tags: addeventlistener, mutation-observers

I don't want to write my understanding of the difference so to bias the question so I'll just ask: What is the main difference between mutationobserver and addeventlistener?

I ask because I'm not sure I understand it correctly and both terms seem to me quite similar.

Comment: Everything is different. The only common thing is that both can be used in a page script. MutationObserver observes DOM mutations, addEventListener registers a callback for a specified event like a mouse click and many others.

Comment: Oh, in the former we observe say the addition of an element (and response in some way), and in the latter - we listen to events regarding an element already existed in `DOMContentLoaded` (or added as a mutation).